# how to parse certain sections of a csv with R

Tags: r

Hi I am new to the R programming language and have a quick question. I need to get the data following [Raw Data for Passive Reference ROX] The csv looks like this:

```
S235-A91    D14 SSEA4+ Tra1-60+ 52  Unknown

Dose Meter Reading Data     
Cycle Number    1        2
ROX            519980   520191
FAM-MGB 62116   62108

Raw Data for Passive Reference ROX      
Chamber ID  1       2
S235-A01    15644   15635
S235-A02    15936   15920
```

with alot more data obviously. Since [Raw Data for Passive Reference ROX] is not a header at the top how would I go about just getting that section, S235-A01 with the values? Currently I was screwing around and have: `test <- read.csv(file="myFile.csv",head=TRUE,sep=",")` but not sure what to do because I cannot do: test$RawDataforPassiveReferenceROX. Any help would be appreciated, thanks. -Sam

Comment: Could you also show the expected result based on the above dataset?  Also, is this pattern repeated?

Comment: pattern is not repeated, the data set for [Raw Data for Passive Reference ROX] is around 40k lines and then ends with a white space before the next data set. The result that I need is the ID followed by the cycle values. IE - S235-A0l, 15644, 15635. Then the next one S235-A02, 15936, 15920.

Comment: You mentioned the pattern is not repeated.  So, what do you mean by `ends with a white space before the next data set`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
 lines <- readLines("file.txt")
 indx <- grep("^Chamber",  lines)

 dat <- read.table(text=lines[(indx+1):length(lines)], 
          sep="", header=FALSE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, check.names=FALSE)

  colnames(dat) <- strsplit(gsub("(?<=Chamber) ", "_", 
                      lines[indx], perl=TRUE), " +")[[1]]

 dat
 #  Chamber_ID     1     2
 #1   S235-A01 15644 15635
 #2   S235-A02 15936 15920
```

Comment: just stops dead at dat <- read.table(text=lines[(indx+1):length(lines)], 
                  sep="", header=FALSE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, check.names=FALSE)

Comment: @user3558177 My code was based on the data you pasted.  Can you show few lines of `lines` or if possible you can share the file in `dropbox`

Comment: Na I would get in trouble, but what you gave me should be enough to help me figure out R lol. Ill just step by step it to find the problem cheers.